# Create sites(groups) programmatically in liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

The past week I've been trying to make this work but I just can't get it done myself(I'm new to both java and liferay). So I was hoping someone could help.

I'm trying to make sites in liferay with the press of a button so users can create their own. Here's some of the code I have already:

```
public void addGroup(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)  {
    
    ThemeDisplay theme = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);  
    
    long userId = theme.getUserId();
    
    String friendly = "/hilversum";
    
    String name = "hilversum";
    
    Map<Locale, String> nameMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
    nameMap.put(LocaleUtil.NETHERLANDS, name);
    
    try {
        GroupLocalServiceUtil.addGroup( userId, GroupConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_GROUP_ID, "", 37632, GroupConstants.DEFAULT_LIVE_GROUP_ID, 
                nameMap, null, GroupConstants.TYPE_SITE_OPEN, false, GroupConstants.DEFAULT_MEMBERSHIP_RESTRICTION, friendly, true, true, new ServiceContext() );
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

This method is used in my jsp when someone presses submit on a form with a portlet actionURL.
When I press the button however I get an exception: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.GroupKeyException
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.validateGroupKey(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:4868)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.addGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:387)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.GroupLocalServiceImpl.addGroup(GroupLocalServiceImpl.java:481)

Am I doing something wrong in my code? or are the variables I give to the addGroup method wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *nameMap* you pass to *addGroup* method should have at least your default locale. Try replacing

```java
    nameMap.put(LocaleUtil.NETHERLANDS, name);
```

by

```java
    nameMap.put(LocaleUtil.getDefault(), name);
```

And don't forget to translate the *name* accordingly to the default locale.

**LocaleUtil** package is

```java
    import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.LocaleUtil;
```

obs.: I'm using Liferay version 7.3.10 GA1